# Append to constructor

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

This object constructor is the definition of a person:

```
var Person = function( age, name ){
    this.age = age;
    this.namge = name;
};
```

this is a line of code that will give the prototype of Person an array called "active"

```
Person.prototype.active = [];
```

The reason I am adding this to the prototype, is so that there is only one `active` array that every person, meaning Jim in this case: `var Jim = new Person()` ), SHARES the exact *same* active array.

From that point I want to add in every newly created person into the active array. 
This is how I would do it:

```
var Jim = new Person(age, name);
Jim.active.push( Jim );
var Tim = new Person(age, name);
Tim.active.push( Tim );
```

What I expected from this, is for Tim.active[0] to be Jim and for
Jim.active[1] to be Tim.

The problem is, is that I want the `active.push[ self id ]` to be called 
when a new Person is created, without the second line doing it. My solution for this would be modifying the Person constructor too look like this:

```
var Person = function( age, name ){
    this.age = age;
    this.namge = name;

    this.active.push( this );// The constructor now adds itself to the array during initiation 
};
```

As you can see, it puhes itself into the `active` array. The problem is that I want my object to do exactly this, but I want the constructor to begin like the first one I provided with `this.active.push` appended later in the code.

How do I expect this to be solved? My thoughts were that since the `active` array could be initiated anytime inside the program, that the functions constructor could somehow append `this.active.push()` to the end of it at right after `Person.prototype.active = []` is executed.

Something that may look like:

```
Person.prototype.active = [];
Person.prototype.append( function(){this.active.push(this)} );
```

The second line would morph the first object constructor to look like the second one.

Comment: Live objects don't have a `.prototype` property.  It's constructor functions that have a `.prototype` property.  If you want to give a live object a property, then just assign the property directly `obj.live = [];`.

Comment: @jfriend00 What I am doing is giving an objects prototype an array called `alive`. I want there to be only one array that holds all instances of each object created by **new object()**. So, every individual instance shares one array that they can all be found in. Kind of like an instance tacker. I wanted to make it so that as soon as a `new` object is created it adds itself to that specific objects `alive` array.

Comment: You don't seem to understand that an instantiated object does NOT have a `.prototype` property unless it's a function and then the `.prototype` only affects object created from that specific constructor.  Your question is very hard to follow.  I suspect you're trying to do things the hard way, but don't understand enough about what you're trying to do to suggest the easy way out.

Comment: Player and Block are not instantiated objects. They **are** the definition of the objects that will be instantiated. IE: `Player = function(){ this.x = 0; this.y = 0 }`. So they do, as far as I know, have a prototype.

Comment: Geez.  Why didn't you show what Player was?  Your code says it's an object.  I give up.  Too confusing and not enough relevant code shown.

Comment: So have you confirmed that your objects successfully have the alive array accessible on their prototype chain?

Comment: @jfriend00 I thought I had to much honestly! I completely forgot to   add that part in the post. Thanks for the help though, I know it's not easy when people aren't completely sure of themselves (me).

Comment: @Aweary yes, the `alive` array in the prototype are accessible through the main objects prototype and each of its derived instances.

Comment: What happens when you try to use the push method? If Player.prototype.alive accesses a valid array then you should be able to call its methods

Comment: Ever heard of inheritance?  If you want a whole bunch of object types to have a common set of properties or methods, then inherit from a common type of object.  Then you just assign the properties to the base object prototype and all derived objects automatically inherit them.  There's no dynamic assigning of anything.

Comment: "*it adds itself into an array*" sounds like a very bad idea. A constructor should not have any side effects. Use an extra factory function for such things, in an object that also maintains the array.

Comment: I think the way I wrote it now makes more sense. Would anyone care to reread my problem?

Comment: I do not understand the part starting with `The problem is that I my object to do exactly this, but I want to write it like the first object constructor that did not have the this.active.push`. Can you please reformulate that part.

Comment: @try-catch-finally alright I rewrote it. And just for extra clarification, I just want `this.active.push` to be executed in the creation of a new instance.

Comment: I'm staggered. Your fourth code block `function Person(){ ... ; this.active.push(this); }`  just does this. From the text following it I'd speculate, that you fear that something might be able to access the array before it has been initialized. If this is your concern: it's your code - just avoid it. Otherwise you might "statically" bind "active" as property to `Person`: `function Person(){ ... ; Person.active.push(this); }; Person.active = []; ... `

Comment: @try-catch-finally Well the purpose of this was to dynamically add it in. It's main purpose wasn't to catch anything in, but to simply add the functionality without actually writing inside of every object that required it. Like how the array was dynamically added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want this approach, perhaps it can be refactored? Probably better to have some sort of PersonMediator "class" in my opinion. But, if you want to have the prototype include an active array that has conditions, then attach some way to manage those conditions to the Person object.

```js
var Person = function( age, name ){
    this.age = age;
    this.namge = name;
    
    //checks for activation flag
    this.ready();
};

Person.prototype.active = [];
Person.activate = function(){ Person.prototype.activate = true; };
Person.deactivate = function(){ Person.prototype.activate = false; };
Person.prototype.activate = false;

Person.prototype.ready = function(){
 //depending on activate flag, appends to active array
 if( this.activate ) this.append();
};
Person.prototype.append = function(){
 //array append
 this.active.push(this);  
};

var Jim = new Person(10,'Jim');//not added, default flag false
//activate flag for appending
Person.activate();
var Tim = new Person(20,'Tim');//now added to the active array
console.log(Jim.active);//shows only Tim
console.log(Tim.active);//shows only Tim
```

---

That said, this is how I would manage this.

```js
var Person = function( age, name ){
    this.age = age;
    this.namge = name;
};
var PersonMediator = function(){
 this.alive = [];
 this.removed = [];
};
PersonMediator.prototype.create = function(age, name){
 var person = new Person(age,name);
 this.alive.push(person);
 return person;
};
PersonMediator.prototype.remove = function(person){
 for(var i = 0; i < this.alive.length; i++){
  if( this.alive[i] === person ){
   this.alive.splice(i,1);  
  }
 }
 this.removed.push(person);  
};

var pm = new PersonMediator();
var Jim = pm.create(10,'Jim');
var Tim = pm.create(20,'Tim');
console.log(pm.alive);
```

Comment: My question was a question, that's where everyone went wrong. If there wasn't an actual feasible way of doing what I wanted to do in Javascript, I wish someone would have just bluntly said:"that's not a reasonable practice in javascript". Yours basically answers that, and gives an example of what I could do instead; that makes it the best answer. The problem that I have with your example is your create and remove function of the person mediator are object specific and could be generalized(I think at least) to work for multiple objects with differences. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to store the instantiated objects to an array, you can use an inheritance pattern like so:

```
var myArray = [];

function SuperClass() {
  myArray.push(this);
};

function Block(name) {
  this.name = name;
  SuperClass.apply(this, arguments);
};

function Player(name) {
  this.name = name;
  SuperClass.apply(this, arguments);
};

var baller = new Player('Jim');
var blocker = new Block('Joe');
console.log(myArray); // [Player, Block]
```

Every time a new instance of `Player` or `Block` is instantiated, it will add it to the array.

Comment: This merges every object together regardless of type. What I am trying to accomplish is so that Player's and Blocks aren't mixed together inside the same array. They are segmented for object indexing. And what I was trying to do was refrain from inserting the code that adds to the main array inside the original function.

Answer (score 0):

Another pattern you may consider is having a set prototype object that you can add your prototypical methods and shared data to, and then assigning it as the prototype in your constructor function

```
var personPrototype = {
    alive: []
}

var blockPrototype = {
    alive: []
}



    var Person = function(x, y){
    //this creates a new object with the prototype of our personPrototype object
    var o = Object.create(personPrototype);

    //then we can configure / add instance-specific attributes and return the object
      o.x = x;
      o.y = y;
      return o;
}

    var Block = function(x, y){
      var o = Object.create(blockPrototype);
      o.x = x;
      o.y = y; 
      return o;

}



var me = new Person(1, 2);
var square = new Block(10, 20);

// > []
me.alive
```

By using Object.create to create a dummy object we can effectively assign it a proper prototype. Then we can add whatever instance attributes we'd like, and return that object. This means that the personPrototype will be a proper prototype. Each instance can use instance.alive or instance.alive.push directly, since it automatically walks up the prototype chains

It also allows you to easily add any new data to the prototype of all your instances. You don't need to iterate through each instance and add prototypical methods. You can just add the method to the prototype to start and it will be accessible on all instances by default.

Answer (score -1):

I find the whole approach - trying to track/store `[Person]`  instances - questionable.

But if I was in the position of being told to do so, I'd go for an approach that is build upon a
factory module. Thus being at least able of assuring "read only access" to the list of all instances
that ever got created by the factory.

A possible implementation than might look similar to the following example:

```
var Person = (function (global, Object, Array, Math) {


  var
    array_from  = ((typeof Array.from == "function") && Array.from) || (function (array_prototype_slice) {
      return function (listType) {

        return array_prototype_slice.call(listType);
      };
    }(Array.prototype.slice)),


    personModule = {},
    personList   = [],


    Person = function (config) { // constructor.
      var person = this;

      person.name = config.name;
      person.age = config.age;

      person.constructor = Object;
      return person;
    },


    isPerson = function (type) {
      return (type instanceof Person);
    },
    createPerson = function (age, name) { // factory.
      /*
        - sanitizing/validation of arguments etc. should be done right here.
        - create instances only if all the conditions are fulfilled.
      */
      var person = new Person({
        name: name,
        age : age
      });
      personList.push(person);

      return person;
    }/*,
    removePerson = function (type) {
      if (isPerson(type)) {
        // remove person from the internal list.
      }
    }*/
  ;


//personModule.remove   = removePerson;
  personModule.create   = createPerson;
  personModule.isPerson = isPerson;


  personModule.all = function () { // expose internal instance list.

    return array_from(personList);
  };
  personModule.all.size = function () {

    return personList.length;
  };


  (function () { // make [personModule.all] enumerable.
    var
      parse_float = global.parseFloat,
      math_floor  = Math.floor
    ;
    this.first = function () {

      return (this()[0]);
    };
    this.last = function () {
      var list;

      return ((list = this())[list.length - 1]);
    };
    this.item = function (idx) {

      return (this()[math_floor(parse_float(idx, 10))]);
    };
  }).call(personModule.all);


  return personModule;


}((window || this), Object, Array, Math));



var Jim = Person.create("Jim", 21);
var Tim = Person.create("Tim", 19);

console.log("Jim", Jim);
console.log("Tim", Tim);

console.log("Person.isPerson(Jim) ? ", Person.isPerson(Jim));
console.log("Person.isPerson(Tim) ? ", Person.isPerson(Tim));
console.log("Person.isPerson({name: 'Tim', age: 21}) ? ", Person.isPerson({name: 'Tim', age: 21}));

console.log("Person.all.size() : ", Person.all.size());
console.log("Person.all() : ", Person.all());
console.log("Person.all.first() : ", Person.all.first());
console.log("Person.all.last() : ", Person.all.last());
console.log("(Person.all()[1] === Person.all.item(1)) ? ", (Person.all()[1] === Person.all.item(1)));
console.log("(Person.all.first() === Person.all.item(0)) ? ", (Person.all.first() === Person.all.item(0)));
```

Comment: Why was this comment not useful? What is the reason for being downgraded?